# Professional organisation

Tags: professional-societies, organisation, aes

Hi I’m a student about to graduate with an interest of going in to sound design. Was just wondering if anyone was a member or recommend becoming a member of any professional organisation (such as the AES)?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in game audio sound design, GANG (the Game Audio Network Guild) at http://www.audiogang.org/ is a good place to start. They're quite supportive of students and rookies.

AB